# R Package: Call C Function Within Rcpp

Tags: c, r, rcpp, r-package

I am writing an R package that contains C and Rcpp. The goal is to call the C function from R and within Rcpp, eventually performing most of the analysis in Rcpp and only returning to R for minimal tasks. My package compiles and calling my function from R works fine.

```
#generate some matrix. Numeric is fine too. Must have column names, no row names
myMat <- matrix(data = 1:100, nrow = 10, ncol = 10,
                dimnames = list(NULL, LETTERS[1:10]))

#This works. Put in full path, no expansion. It returns null to the console.
MinimalExample::WriteMat(mat = myMat, file = "Full_Path_Please/IWork.csv",
                         sep = "," ,eol = "\n", dec = ".", buffMB = 8L)
```

However, attempting the same thing in Rcpp produces a SIGSEV error. I think the problem is how I am passing arguments to the function, but I can't figure out the proper way.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

extern "C"{
  #include "fwrite.h"
}


//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void WriteMatCpp(String& fileName, NumericMatrix& testMat){

  Rcpp::Rcout<<"I did start!"<<std::endl;

  String patchName = fileName;
  int whichRow = 1;

  std::string newString = std::string(3 - toString(whichRow).length(), '0') 
                                      + toString(whichRow);
  patchName.replace_last(".csv", newString+".csv");


  //Set objects to pass to print function
  String comma = ",";
  String eol = "\n";
  String dot = ".";
  int buffMem = 8;

  //This is where I crash, giving a SIGSEV error
  fwriteMain(testMat, (SEXP)&patchName, (SEXP)&comma, (SEXP)&eol,
                (SEXP)&dot, (SEXP)&buffMem);

}
```

Here is a link to the GitHub repository with the package. https://github.com/GilChrist19/MinimalExample

Comment: I just poked at your package -- thanks for pointing to the source -- and I cannot make heads or tails of it.  It is, and please pardon the French, quite a mess.  Do not include other R headers after Rcpp.h. Things go funky with the exports as well.  I would start over, much smaller, and build up one by one.

Comment: As for the narrower "call C from Rcpp": sure, we do that all the time. The API from R is C; lots of packages call C (not C++) libraries; think eg of RcppGSL.  But you can also access `fwrite()` etc from C++ so keeping it all C++ is perfectly fine too.

Comment: I have a working variant `MinEx` if you care...

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was in class.
I would love to see a working variant! Especially if it cleans up some of my "mess". (I'm not surprised it isn't kosher. Learning from OS is fantastic, but leaves me with an unstructured education. )

Comment: I hear you.  And sometime we start from something (ie the C code you had here from data.table) and want to transform.  It is easy to get lost in the woods. I'll just for your repo and send you PR with my `MinEx`.

Comment: Or maybe, even easier, can you just make me a committer on your MinimalExample repo?  I'll put MinEx into, next to your MinimalExample package.

Comment: Request sent. 
For not including other headers after Rcpp.h, how come, and does that go for things RccpArmadillo and RcppProgress as well? Or not, since they are Rcpp* flavors?

Comment: Commit pushed :)   For the headers, be *very* careful.  But re-including some headers after the original Rcpp.h, you may hide/override/... things.  Not. Good. At. All.  Prime reason why we say "only include RcppArmadillo.h" as ... order matters.  C++ can be finicky.

Comment: So in short, put C definitions in header files source by the .c files, but don't globally include "everything everywhere".  Live and learn :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call from C++ to C is wrong.  You can't just write `(SEXP)&` in front of an arbitrary data structure and hope for it to become a `SEXP`.

#### Fix

Use a line such as this to convert what you have in C++ to the `SEXP` your C function expects using `Rcpp::wrap()` on each argument:

```
  //This is where I crash, giving a SIGSEV error
  fwriteMain(wrap(testMat), wrap(patchName), wrap(comma), 
             wrap(eol), wrap(dot), wrap(buffMem));
```

#### Demo

```
edd@brad:/tmp/MinimalExample/MinEx(master)$ Rscript RunMe.R 
I did start!
edd@brad:/tmp/MinimalExample/MinEx(master)$ cat /tmp/IDoNotWork.csv 
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J
1,11,21,31,41,51,61,71,81,91
2,12,22,32,42,52,62,72,82,92
3,13,23,33,43,53,63,73,83,93
4,14,24,34,44,54,64,74,84,94
5,15,25,35,45,55,65,75,85,95
6,16,26,36,46,56,66,76,86,96
7,17,27,37,47,57,67,77,87,97
8,18,28,38,48,58,68,78,88,98
9,19,29,39,49,59,69,79,89,99
10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100
edd@brad:/tmp/MinimalExample/MinEx(master)$
```

See https://github.com/GilChrist19/MinimalExample/tree/master/MinEx for a complete example.